# Centered div with different colored margins on each side

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a div that is centered horizontally on the page.  To the left of the div I want  the same background color as the div.  To the right I want the same color as the background.  My problem is that as the window gets larger the size of the div grows faster than it should and i get a til on the other end of the div.  How can i fix this?

I have tried the following.

```
<div id="holder">
  <div id="text">
    Text goes here
  </div>
</div>
```

my css:

```
#holder{
background:#3B92C0;
position:relative;
min-width:1090px;
left:-200px;

 }
#text{
position:relative;
width:1090px;
border:0 auto; 
left:200px;
 }
```

here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qhFaD/2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vvqZj/

The idea is to give the `div` containing the text a left margin of `-1000px` and a left padding of `1000px`, so the background will begin 1000px left of where the text begins.

The downside of this method is that you need another wrapper around the text which centers the div containing the text. This is because you cannot set `margin: auto` to the div containing the text, as you overwrite the left margin of this div.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the http://jsfiddle.net/raunakkathuria/qhFaD/3/

Changes

```
 #holder{
background:#3B92C0;
position:relative;
margin:0 auto; 

 }
#text{
position:relative;
width:500px;
background:#555;
text-align:left;
margin:0 auto; 
color:#fff;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

No tail!

http://jsfiddle.net/t2SYv/

```
<div id="regular">THis is a regular centerd div</div>
<div id="holder">
      <div id="text">
        This looks good when window is small but when it grows it gets a tail<br>
          How do i get rid of this tail when window is big ---------------&gt;
      </div>
      <div id="filler"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#regular
{
    background:#ccc;
    height:200px;
    margin:0 auto 10px;
    width:500px;
}

#holder
{
    background:#3B92C0;
    margin:0 auto;
    min-width:500px;
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
}

#text
{
    background:#555;
    color:#fff;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
    text-align:left;
    width:500px;
    z-index:2;
}

#filler
{
    background:#FFF;
    display:inline-block;
    height:100%;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    width:50%;
    z-index:1;
}
```